# How to add primary key column in existing table for hibernate WITHOUT actually adding column to it

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Spring+HibernateDAO and want to access a table which does not have a primary key.
Because [Hibernate requires that entity tables have primary keys.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) ,I need to create some virtual primary key(perhaps), just to fool hibernate (it satisfies with @Id only) Or doing any efforts on database side without touching existing table is also fine.
Please suggest any workaround which does NOT require ALTER EXISTING TABLE , any other table inheritance/structure changes are welcome.

PS. Already using JDBC template with manual mapping of columns to custom object.DB is Sybase ASE15 if it matters.

Comment: Have you looked at composite primary keys with hibernate?  Hopefully there are a set of columns that are unique. If so map those as a composite key.

Comment: @neildo Yes I already tried considering that, but because of type of data in the table and manner its already being used can not use it.

Comment: If you ONLY want to use Hibernate to SELECT from this table, you could use a native query to populate a non-managed entity: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904  

If you want Hibernte to manage INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE then you are out of luck.  You must have an ID.  Identity is a core aspect of Hibernate's entity management.

Comment: Yes you are right @neildo . As my requirement dont include Updates this Idea works for some extent. The reason for only some extent is like :- `q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Y.class)); ` but this fails with: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for some_property. X has a field called someProperty with the appropriate getter and setter but in this case it doesn't seem like Hibernate maps the column name (some_property) to the correct field name. Agree its a good idea but ,I will let the question still open as perhaps we may get more featured solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some many answers to your question on stack-overflow itself, I am surprised, you didn't find one :P

[How to work with tables without PRIMARY KEY in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983493/how-to-work-with-tables-without-primary-key-in-hibernate)

[Hibernate and no PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk)

[Hibernate without Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591255/hibernate-without-primary-key)

This one on [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/440878/ORM/databases/ID-column-table-Hibernate)

Analyse and make your choice :)

Comment: @DarkHorrse Yes the solution 'Hibernate and no PK' works. Actually I just read it too literraly which was mentioned in your third reference earlier ` Hibernate requires that entity tables have primary keys. End of story. ` But you have got the correct way there in Second Solution. Tons of thanks :)